# ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified with jmeter test

Tags: oracle, performance-testing, oracle-19c

I have trying to execute a simple test with jmeter in Oracle 19.7 database. This is my lang configuration in database

```
SQL> select * from nls_database_parameters;
...
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
```

In my linux machine I have this variables

```
$ export LANG=en_us
$ echo $LANG
en_us
$ echo $NLS_LANG
American_America.UTF8
```

and I execute this test

```
$ ./jmeter -n -t ../prueba_select_jdbc.jmx -l /tmp/resultado -e -o /tmp/prueba_jmeter -Jthreads=10 -Jloop=5 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
    Creating summariser <summary>
    Created the tree successfully using ../prueba_select_jdbc.jmx
    Starting standalone test @ Mon Nov 30 19:51:43 CET 2020 (1606762303758)
    Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
    summary =     50 in 00:00:09 =    5.4/s Avg:    51 Min:    29 Max:   556 Err:    50 (100.00%)
    Tidying up ...    @ Mon Nov 30 19:51:53 CET 2020 (1606762313390)
    ... end of run
$
```

and the error that i allways get is

```
null 0/java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1\nORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified\n)
```

I have tried multiple conbinations but none of then works.

Regards

Edit 1:

I have configured instant client and I used sqldeveloper launch from here without problems.

```
$ env |grep ORA
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64
$ set |grep LIB
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/lib
$ echo $PATH
...:/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/bin
```

Comment: I have copied this .jar into jmeter /lib. 
`./jlib/orai18n-servlet.jar
./jlib/orai18n-utility.jar
./jlib/orai18n.jar
./jlib/orai18n-mapping.jar
./jlib/orai18n-collation.jar`
but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

As per [Oracle FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-nls-lang.html)

> Setting the NLS_LANG environment parameter is the simplest way to specify locale behavior for Oracle software. It sets the language and territory used by the client application and the database server. It also indicates the client's character set, which corresponds to the character set for data to be entered or displayed by a client program.

So you can try explicitly setting `user.country` and `user.language` Java system properties, either add the next lines to *system.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
user.country=us
user.language=en
```

or pass these properties via `-D` command-line arguments like:

```
./jmeter -Duser.country=us -Duser.language=en -n -t .....
```

References:

- [How to change the LOCALE (Language and Country) and TIMEZONE for the IBM Technology for Java (IT4J) VM on the IBM i](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-change-locale-language-and-country-and-timezone-ibm-technology-java-it4j-vm-ibm-i)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I use the country and language parameters when execute jmeter command but it doesn't works. This is my original command.
$ ./jmeter -n -t ../prueba_select_jdbc.jmx -l /tmp/resultado -e -o /tmp/prueba_jmeter -Jthreads=10 -Jloop=5 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en